# Error instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState': on Linux server

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a Scala Spark application that I'm trying to run on a Linux server using a shell script. I am getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error
>   while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':

However, I don't understand what is wrong. I am doing this to instantiate Spark:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HDFStoES").setMaster("local")

      val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

Am I doing this correctly, if so what could be the error?

Comment: Are you using Java / Python. Can you clarify this. I suspect your using java. If so  please implement the program according to java standards / use appropriate java packages.

Comment: It's actually Scala

Answer (score 0):

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test App").master("local[*])
                .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", hiveWareHouseDir)
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", hiveWareHouseDir).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
```

Use above, you need to specify the `"hive.metastore.warehouse.dir"` directory to enable hive support in spark session.